# Random walk: Use stirling formula for asymptotic estimate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We are given the Stirling formula $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac n e)^n$. Now let $Z_n$ be a random walk $Z_n=\sum_{i=0}^n X_i$ where $X_i \sim (\text{Unif}\{-1,1\})$ independent. Prove that:

$$\mathbb P [Z_{2n}=0] \sim \frac 1 {\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

---

I have found on the internet that we have $\mathbb P [Z_{2n}=0] = \text{Binomial}(n;2n,\frac 1 4)$.

Now while this seems to be a very good start, I'm not exactly sure how to argue this equality. I would attempt something like this, but it's not really complete/correct:

Define a Bernoulli experiment where the success means that two "unused" numbers ($-1$ or $1$) add to $0$. After that they count as "used". We do this experiment $2n$ times and we want $n$ successes, so the total sum is $0$. We have $p = \frac 1 4$ as we need two numbers to "match", and one has probability $\frac 1 2$. This would yield the above equation.

However, I don't think this argument is fully correct. Can someone tell me how to actually argue the equality?

---

However, continuing the calculation, we get:

$$\mathbb P [Z_{2n}=0] = \text{Binomial}(n;2n,\frac 1 4) = \binom{2n}{n} \frac 1 {4^n} (\frac 3 4)^n = \frac 2 {n!} (\frac 3 {16})^n$$

Now, apply Stirling:

$\dots \sim \frac 2 {\sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n} (\frac 3 {16})^n = \sqrt 2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{\pi n}} (\frac{3e}{16n})^n$

But $(\frac{3e}{16n})^n$ would go against $0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. So something must be wrong in my calculations. Can someone help me?

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n}$ is not somehow $(2n/n)!/(n!)$, instead it is what Benjamin wrote